# IOS - UIWebview - Get the URL of the link clicked and edit the url

Tags: iphone, ios, url, webview, get

I'm creating an app which has a webview. When user click to a link or a button in the webview, I want to be able to get the new url, and edit the new url.

First I initialize the webview with the following url:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
   NSString *id = @"12212323";

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"www.website.com/index.php?id=%@", id];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

When I click to a link, for example www.website.com/contact.php

Then I edit the new url with www.website.com/contact.php**?id=12212323**

I need to keep the id parameter in all the urls.

Comment: want you make visible URL? and if you edit is like a web browser?

Comment: no I don't want the user to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The [UIWebViewDelegateProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) should suit your requirements.
In particular the method `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it, and put some NSLog inside the method but it never call that method

Comment: You should se the delegate

Answer (score 0):

this is a code to get the current URL

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {    
       NSString *id = @"12212323";

        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *fullURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"www.website.com/index.php?id=%@", id];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

        NSURL *currentURL = [requestObj URL];
        NSLog(@"Current URL is %@", currentURL.absoluteString);
    }
```

but to create a URL bar hidden or not is a lot of code, you can start from this tutorial on YouTube is simple and work very well, is possible give you other idea to make a good job ;)

[Web Browser Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vpq8r-HHwZA)

hope this help you